# Type error when passing Ocaml a file from the command line but not in repl

Tags: ocaml

My code gives an error when run from a file but runs fine when pasted into the Ocaml repl. I have saved the following as test.ml:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)

let words = StringSet.add StringSet.empty "something";;
```

When run from bash with "ocaml test.ml" I get:

```
File "test.ml", line 3, characters 26-41:
Error: This expression has type StringSet.t = Set.Make(String).t
       but an expression was expected of type StringSet.elt = string
```

When pasted into the Ocaml repl I get:

```
# module StringSet = Set.Make(String)

let words = StringSet.add StringSet.empty "something";;
    module StringSet :
  sig
(* ... much more output ... *)
  end
val words : StringSet.t = <abstr>
#
```

Everything seems to work fine from the repl.
My Ocaml version is reported by the repl as: OCaml version 4.02.1.

Does anyone know why the error is produced when running "ocaml test.ml"?

Comment: There's some chance that your `.ocamlinit` is opening a module which is causing the difference.

Comment: In the repl always remember to close and restart it before wondering too much about errors. Previous input can easily affect the results.

Comment: Thanks gsg. My .ocamlinit did have an open statement in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StringSet.add` function takes the element (the string) as the first parameter and the set (`StringSet.empty`) as the second parameter. You have them in the opposite order.

When I try your code I get the same error in both cases. When I invert the parameter order I don't get an error in either case.

I'm using OCaml 4.06.0, but I would really doubt that the paramter order has changed.